# Are html styles valid inside Docbook and TEI documents?

Tags: javascript, xml, web-applications, wysiwyg, docbook

Im working on a webapplication where you can make docbook and TEI documents and I know that docbook and TEI has its own tags for bold, italic ect. text but I would like to use some wysiwyg editor to make those text styles.
Currently Im using NicEdit which is fine but I dont know if its valid for docbook and TEI to contain html code like <b> text </b> or < font color="red"> text </font> inside its nodes which is made by NiceEdit 
Since I could not find the answer could you tell me wether its valid to do this way or my idea is wrong?

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: by the way I was clearly asking for advice not the solution in code format ...

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is wrong.

DocBook is logical markup.  Presentation matters are defined in stylesheets.